# MongoDB signal to application

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Short question:

Can MongoDB contact application if something is changed in collection? Some kind of trigger which will signal application that some field is changed or added or something like that?

Comment: MongoDB does not possess triggers, most def not ones of that kind. Not sure which dbs do. Normally the application does a pub/sub on the db

Answer (score 2):

If you can leverage the spring-data-mongodb then you can take advantage of its [implicit support of events](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongodb.mapping-usage.events) to meet your requirements.

- onBeforeConvert - called in MongoTemplate insert, insertList and save operations before the object is converted to a DBObject using a MongoConveter.
- onBeforeSave - called in MongoTemplate insert, insertList and save operations before inserting/saving the DBObject in the database.
- onAfterSave - called in MongoTemplate insert, insertList and save operations after inserting/saving the DBObject in the database.
- onAfterLoad - called in MongoTempnlate find, findAndRemove, findOne and getCollection methods after the DBObject is retrieved from the database.
- onAfterConvert - called in MongoTempnlate find, findAndRemove, findOne and getCollection methods after the DBObject retrieved from the database was converted to a POJO.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no callback mechanism.

Better to a) poll the document for changes from your application, b) use a message queue (RabbitMQ for example) to publish changes from the application that's changing the data to subscribers who want to know when the data changes. A complex solution might be c) tail the oplog, see [MongoConnector](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/tree/master/mongo-connector#system-internals). Your MongoDB must be part of a replica set for this to work.